# Computational complexity of a piece of code

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have got a program, and trying to compute its complexity. I want to be sure i am not mistaken

```
for(int i=4; i<=n; i=i*4)
{
    cout<<"counter for first loop: "<<++count1<<endl;
    for(int j=i;j>=0;j=j-4)
    {
        cout<<"counter for second loop: "<<++count2<<endl;
        for(int k=0;k<=n;k++)
        {
            cout<<"counter for third loop: "<<++count3<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the complexity of third loop is O(n), then together with the second loop, the complexity becomes O(n.log<sub>4</sub>i), and the complexity of whole program is O(n.(log<sub>4</sub>i)<sup>2</sup>). Am i right in my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of the inner most loop is O(n). The complexity of the middle one is O(i/4), which in turn is O(i). The complexity of the outer most loop is O(log<sub>4</sub>n). There for the total complexity of the code is O(n.i.log<sub>4</sub>n) which is equal to O (n.(log<sub>4</sub>n)<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed formally like the following:

[image]

Executing this fragment:

```
sum = 0;
for( i = 4 ;  i <= n;  i = i * 4 ) {
    for( j = i ; j >= 0 ; j = j - 4 ) {
        for( k = 0 ; k <= n ; k ++ ) {
            sum ++;
        }
    }
}
```

We obtain:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Results exactly compatible with the formula above.

Besides, both inner loops' runtime is O(n) ... which means that, when executed together, we get O(n²).